# Getting data from facebook xml

Tags: php, facebook, http-get

I have a problem, I'm trying to get some data for a unique link to my site.

When people are viewing eg: video.php?id=23 i want the script to get the data for that site using `$_GET['id']`.

Here's my script, and I've tried everything. Hope you can help me!

```
<?php
$vidurl = $_GET['id'];
function fb_count() {
global $fbcount;
$facebook = file_get_contents('http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://www.fniis.dk/video.php?id=$vidurl');
$fbbegin = '<share_count>'; $fbend = '</share_count>';
$fbpage = $facebook;
$fbparts = explode($fbbegin,$fbpage);
$fbpage = $fbparts[1];
$fbparts = explode($fbend,$fbpage);
$fbcount = $fbparts[0];
if($fbcount == '') { $fbcount = '0'; }
}
fb_count();
?>
```

The problem is that it wont let me print the $vidurl, it doesnt seem to work, because it is only getting data from the following link : fniis.dk/video.php?id= and not eg: fniis.dk/video.php?id=123

Comment: What specifically is the problem?  Can you be more descriptive?  Your question isn't clear.

Comment: The problem is that it wont let me print the $vidurl, it doesnt seem to work, because it is getting data from the following link : http://www.fniis.dk/video.php?id=

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems in your code.

**First**, you won't be able to access `$vidurl` in `fb_count()` unless you specify it as global inside `fb_count()`:

```
global $vidurl;
```

It is recommended that you pass `$vidurl` as a parameter `fb_count()` instead of using `global`.

**Second**, your concatenation of `$vidurl` in `file_get_contents` is incorrect. You should be using double quotes instead of single quotes so `$vidurl` will be processed by PHP. It also wouldn't hurt to use `urlencode()` here:

```
// note: using single quotes here and just concatenating with "."
$facebook = file_get_contents('http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://www.fniis.dk/video.php?id=' . urlencode($vidurl));
```

That should get your code working.